# Lambda function for AWS IOT Button in java

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I want to develop java lambda function to identify AWS IOT button click events. I want to identify "SINGLE" Click , double-click and Long press events of AWS IOT button. 
Above all are possible in node.js. Is there any support available in Java to identify AWS IOT button click events?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've converted the Python version that sends email to Java [here](https://github.com/stdunbar/awsiotbutton).  The [code](https://github.com/stdunbar/awsiotbutton/blob/70ff734941b18e2687b41f2420136c56ad63c574/src/main/java/com/hotjoe/aws/lambda/model/IOTButtonRequest.java#L27-L29) allows you to get the String that represents the click type.